# return proper object from angular http.get with promise

Tags: angular, http, promise

I have a http get function which grabs the data structure, but I really would like to have the actual object (I have functions on it).

```
public async get(guid: string): Promise<PctLayer>
{
    return await this.http.get<PctLayer>(`${this.url}/${guid}`, { headers: this.header }).toPromise();
}
```

I can solve that by

```
let layer = Object.assign(new PctLayer(), await this.layerService.get(info.id));
```

which does the job nicely. Is there a way to move the Object.assign into the async get? I couldn't get it to work together with the Promise, ie I'm not sure how to still return a Promise when I call Object.assign in the async get.

I know there's different solution rather than using Object.assign, but they involve a whole lot more code, and I like to keep code short and simple to use.

Comment: You haven't shown how you tried, but there are at least two obvious ways to do this: with a `.pipe(map(...))` on the observable before converting to a promise, or with a `.then(...)` afterwards.

Comment: I've been using this: https://github.com/weichx/cerialize in the last two years for that. `let layer = Deserialize(await this.layerService.get(info.id), PctLayer);`. After **a lot of tries**, I kept using this library since it's the only one I found that actually performs a clever serialization and deserialization. Also, it works with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

```
return await this.http.get<PctLayer>(`${this.url}/${guid}`, { headers: this.header })
.map(r => {
  Object.assign(new PctLayer(), r);
})
.toPromise()
```

May work for you. Just include `Object.assign` inside observable chain, before mapping it to promise

### Edit

Because I'm form RxJS 5 era, below is 6.x version as well:

```
return await this.http.get<PctLayer>(`${this.url}/${guid}`, { headers: this.header })
.pipe(map(r => {
  Object.assign(new PctLayer(), r);
}))
.toPromise()
```

### One more edit

On my presonal projects, when I need to inject data from HTTP fetch to an object, I'd usually just construct new object with REST-response as input parameter:

```
export interface MyClassInterface {
  A: string;
}
export class MyClass implements MyClassInterface{
  public A: string;
  constructor(iIn: MyClassInterface) {
    this.A = iIn.A
    /* and so on */
  }
  public myUsefulFinction() { /*Do stuff*/ }
}
```

Then assuming, that GET-response is compatible with interface, you can just

```
return await this.http.get<PctLayer>(`${this.url}/${guid}`, { headers: this.header })
.pipe(map(ifc => MyClass(ifc)))
.toPromise()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That doesn't work for me. It's looking through the properties and methods in PctLayer and throws an error that they don't exist:

Type {} is not assignable to PctLayer. Property ... is missing in {}

Comment: (I'm on version 6)